# JQuery selector for href

Tags: jquery-selectors

I was using with jquery version 1.8.2

```
var hasContainerTab = $("#tabs").find("a[href='#container'").length == 1;
```

I upgraded jquery to 1.12.4. Now that statement is failing saying

> unrecognized expression: a[href='#container'

I referred different blogs like (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2829) around this, but I could not find a fix.

Can any one tell me how to re-write the statement as per the new version?

Comment: your expression misses the closing bracket `]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, since it misses the closing bracket `]`. Use:

```
var hasContainerTab = $("#tabs").find("a[href='#container']").length == 1;
```